# Smartface onSelectedItem, onLongTouch events not working

Tags: smartface.io

I want to run onSelectedItem and onLongTouch events when I clicked or long touched the rows. This codes are not working. My codes as follows. How can I run this?

```js
var myDataSource = [{
        row : "First Row"
    }, {
        row : "Second Row"
    }, {
        row : "Third Row"
    }
];

repeatBox1.dataSource = myDataSource;
repeatBox1.onRowRender = function (e) {
    this.controls[0].text = myDataSource[e.rowIndex].row;
};
repeatBox1.onSelectedItem = function (e) {
    alert("Selected " + (e.rowIndex + 1) + ". row");
};

repeatBox1.onLongTouch= function (e) {
        alert("long touch");
};

repeatBox1.itemTemplate.height = Device.screenHeight / 7;
repeatBox1.itemTemplate.imageFillType = SMF.UI.ImageFillType.stretch;
repeatBox1.itemTemplate.add(lbl);

repeatBox1.useActiveItem = true;
Pages.Page4.add(repeatBox1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. This is for all of controls touchEnabled property have to be false in RepeatBox.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if these functions works for specific items. In the repeatbox guide they say: 
*onSelectedItem: "Creates action(s) that are run when **an item is selected** on the repeat box.".
*onTouch: Creates action(s) that are run when **the object** is touched from device’s screen.

But I'm not sure of that, thats what I got from the documentation.
Hope that helps :)

Comment: Hello sir, I solved my problem, thank you for your interest. I added a new answer.